# Checking Selected data and validating it with data in an array object

Tags: php, arrays, validation, isset

Im trying to validate data selected by users (movie time/day) with times/days that are already stored in an array. So if the users selects Monday 12:30, it will check to see if Monday 12:30 is listed as a time for that movie and validate accordingly.

so far iv created the arrays and function with variables and if/else statements but it doesn't seem to be correct since its not working :/

my tools.php page with arrays/statments:

```php
$moviesObject = [
  'ACT' => [
      'title' => 'Avengers: Endgame',
      'rating' => 'PG-13',
      'description' => 'Add the description here',
      'screenings' => [
          'WED' => 'T21',
          'THU' => 'T21',
          'FRI' => 'T21',
          'SAT' => 'T18',
          'SUN' => 'T18'
      ]
  ],
  'RMC' => [
      'title' => 'Top End Wedding',
      'rating' => 'M',
      'description' => 'Add the description here',
      'screenings' => [
          'MON' => 'T18',
          'TUE' => 'T18',
          'SAT' => 'T15',
          'SUN' => 'T15'
      ]
  ],
  'ANM' => [
      'title' => 'Dumbo',
      'rating' => 'PG-13',
      'description' => 'Add the description here',
      'screenings' => [
          'MON' => 'T12',
          'TUE' => 'T12',
          'WED' => 'T18',
          'THU' => 'T18',
          'FRI' => 'T18',
          'SAT' => 'T12',
          'SUN' => 'T12'
      ]
  ],
  'AHF' => [
      'title' => 'The Happy Prince',
      'rating' => 'R',
      'description' => 'Add the description here',
      'screenings' => [
          'WED' => 'T12',
          'THU' => 'T12',
          'FRI' => 'T12',
          'SAT' => 'T18',
          'SUN' => 'T18'
      ]
  ]
];

$pricesObject = [
  'full' => [
      'STA' => '19.80',
      'STP' => '17.50',
      'STC' => '15.30',
      'FCA' => '30.00',

      'FCP' => '27.00',
      'FCC' => '24.00'
  ],
  'disc' => [
      'STA' => '14.00',
      'STP' => '12.50',
      'STC' => '11.00',
      'FCA' => '24.00',
      'FCP' => '22.50',
      'FCC' => '21.00'
  ]
];

$legalTime = $moviesObject[$_POST['movie']['id']['screenings'][$_POST['movie']['day']]];
if (isset($legalTime) && $legalTime == $_POST['movie']['hour']) {
  $correctTime = "Movie is playing at that time";
}
else {
  $errorTime = "Movie is not playing at that time";
  $totalErrors++;
}
```

my index.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$title = "Lunardo Cinema";
$style="style.css";
include("tools.php");
?>

  <div class="gallery">
      <img src="../../media/TopEndWedding.jpg" alt="topendwedding" id="RMC" onclick="ChangeSynopsis2(this)">
    <div class="desc"><h3><?php echo $Movies[1][0] ?></h3> Monday - Tuesday: 6pm <br>Wed - Friday: -<br>Saturday - Sunday: 3pm </div>
  </div>

<div class="row3">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div id="buttons">
      <button onclick="chosentime1()" id="Wed2">Wednesday 9pm</button>
      <button onclick="chosentime2()" id="Thu2">Thursday 9pm</button>
      <button onclick="chosentime3()" id="Fri2">Friday 9pm</button>
      <button onclick="chosentime4()" id="Sat2">Saturday 6pm</button>
      <button onclick="chosentime5()" id="Sun2">Sunday 6pm</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>   

<h3 id="chosenmovie" value="chosenmovie">Movie Title:</h3><h3 id="movietime" value="movietime"> Movie Time/Date:</h3>
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $errorTime;?></span>
        <input type="hidden" id="movie-id" name="movie[id]" value="">
        <input type="hidden" id="movie-hour" name="movie[day]" value="">
        <input type="hidden" id="movie-day" name="movie[hour]" value="">
```

Comment: Is the movie object coming from a database if if not, why not? My guess is that you have to cast these values to matched types.

Comment: its kind of like a school project, they dont want us to use databases just php/js with arrays and stuff. and yes some of the buttons will not match the times in the array, but if they do it should correctly validate it